# Can a Metro application be aware of other apps?

Tags: windows, process, microsoft-metro, windows-runtime

Is there any way of listing all the running metro applications from a metro app? I'm thinking about a metro Task Manager.

Answer (score 5):

Metro applications' awareness of each other is limited to the Sharing contracts available through the Share charm. Doing something like a Task Manager would require using something like a dashboard approach with the data pulled from a service running on the Desktop side, which would probably be impractical.

Comment: Can you develop on how to do it from a service?

Answer (score 3):

I don't think so.
Metro Apps run in a sandbox, like in Windows Phone.

Comment: If you are a good programmer, you can hook dll calls, metro launcher exe(s), plus; collect all sub-directories in metro apps, and with these informations - you can look the whole system which store app is currently working or not. I mean, if you can see your metro apps running in Windows 8 Task Manager, so, there should be a way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

The solid answer is no. Metro applications cannot enumerate other Metro applications on the same system. At the same Metro applications cannot be "aware" (as you put it) of desktop apps, and neither can desktop apps be (technically) aware of Metro apps.

But there is a case where this is not true. The LoopBack function of Metro apps is disabled when they are delivered through the Microsoft store. However, when they are side loaded or loaded through an enterprise portal, LoopBack may be enabled - this allows Metro apps to communicate back to the same box, effectively with a desktop application that might be listening.

Comment: I think of a scenario where Metro and Desktop can exchange data through i.e. public webservices. Do you thind there can be open TCP-kind of channels between Desktop and Metro, locally? I.e. for JSON data and such.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot loop through other Metro apps.
You can, however, use contracts to share information between Metro style apps. 
As Jerry Nixon mentioned in another answer, you can do it for sideloaded apps. 
Desktop apps are different and behave differently. You can access running desktop (not metro) apps